# How to display content if on a certain post page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type

I'm trying to figure out how to display content only if I'm on a certain custom post type page. So I'm assuming I'm going to use an IF statement although I'm just not sure how I would be able to do identify if I'm on the page that I need.

For example if I"m on a custom post type at example.com/fruits/apple

I would like to than be able to query a specific wordpress query, although I'm just not sure how I would identify in the if statement if I"m on the proper page since I will have multiple if statements checking to see which custom post type page I'm on that way it can display the corresponding information if I"m on that page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(get_post_type() == 'your post type') {
    //do something 
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

Comment: Thanks, but I need not the post type but to know if we are on a certain post within a post type.

Comment: if you can explain yourself a little better, then i'll be able to help; 

Do you mean if you are viewing a single post within a post type?